# How to retrieve all unique key of Table from database in ComboBox

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, combobox

```
public List<Room> GetAll()
{
     return DBContext.Rooms.ToList();
}
```

This function returns whole data of `room` Table and I am using this function to show data in `DataGridView`:

```
RoomFactory fac=new RoomFactory();
RoomView.DataSource= fac.GetAll();
```

`RoomFactory` is a connection class getting `room` and assigning to `DataGridView`
in `EventHandler`.

Now I need same query to retrieve all `id`'s of `room` table in `ComboBox`.

Comment: *Now I need same query to retrieve all id's* ... what's the question?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx). By using `Select` you can projects each element of a sequence into a new form. And also change the method type to `List<int>` or type of `id`'s Like this:

```
public List<int> GetAll()
{
    return DBContext.Rooms.Select(c => c.id).ToList();
}
```